# Arc length with trig vectors

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, arc-length

A particle moves with speed  $s'(t)=|t\sin t|$ in direction $(\sin t \tanh t,\cos t \tanh t,\operatorname{sech} t)$  at time $t$. What is the length of the arc that it travels from $t=0$ to $t=\pi$?

Normally I would normalize the direction vector and multiply by $t\sin t$.  However in this case, I don't know how to normalize the vector. Am I missing something?

Comment: speed is not unit; arc length  $ s = \int t \, \sin t dt $ Further data about orientation required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arc length is simply

$$s(\pi)=\int_{0}^{\pi} |t\sin t| \, dt$$

Since $t\in [0,\pi] \implies \sin t\ge 0$, and using integration by parts

\begin{align}
  s(\pi) &= \int_{0}^{\pi} t\sin t \, dt \\
  &= [-t\cos t]_{0}^{\pi}+\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos t \, dt \\
  &= \pi
\end{align}

Note that $\mathbf{T}(t)=(\sin t \tanh t,\cos t \tanh t,\operatorname{sech} t)$ is already a unit tangent vector.  So the velocity is simply

$$\mathbf{v}(t)=|t\sin t|(\sin t \tanh t,\cos t \tanh t,\operatorname{sech} t)$$

Comment: I guess I got baited into thinking that this question was significantly harder than it is, while the direction vector is actually irrelevant.